# The cardinality of a set of functions

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

I'm given a function $f$ from $\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}$,
and a set $A$ which is defined this way: 
$h$ belongs to $A$ if and only if:

1. $h$ is a function from $\mathbb N\to \{0,1\}$
2. **If there exists a natural number k** , $\forall i\geq k, f(i)=h(i)$.

I'm asked to find the cardinality of $A$.

p.s I cannot use any cardinality arithmetic yet..

Clues or hints will be very helpful!! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple clues:

- $A$ must be infinite because we can define an onto function from $A$ to $\mathbb{N}$ that maps $h\in A$ to the minimum $k \in \mathbb{N}$ corresponding to that $h$ such that $k$ satisfies 2. from your post. Maybe you can work out the details as to why this mapping is onto.
- To prove that $A$ is countably infinite, we can use a one-to-one function from $A$ into any countably infinite set. This includes $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ and other such sets, so if you can find a way of uniquely specifying each element in $A$ with two integers (maybe the first integer is the $k$ from my first point), then you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thank you!! It really helped me solving the problem :)

Answer (score 1):

The definition of $h$ is fixed as $h(i)=f(i)$ for $i\ge k$, and it can be assigned at will either $0$ or $1$ for $0< i <k$. Which gives $2\cdot2\cdot...\cdot2=2^{k-1}$ possible functions. So cardinality of $A$ is $2^{k-1}$

As noted in the comments, this answer if for $\mathbb N=\{1,2,3,...\}$. If $0\in \mathbb N$, then the answer is $2^k$

Comment: Depends if $0 \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: i updated it...

Comment: What if $k$ is not fixed, i.e. it can vary with $h$?

Comment: @confused_wallet Then $A$ a countably infinite union of finite sets, so it is countable (its cardinality is $\aleph_0$)